# azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-certificates gives Null for keystore location

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to use 'azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-certificates' starter jar to load the keystore and trust store into my spring boot application based on this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault-certificates

The steps I did are as below

1. Created a spring boot application with the dependencies suggested on the above page
2. Created a new Vault, and uploaded a certificate
3. Created an app, provided all permissions, and attached it to access policy

However, when I start the application I get this error:

```
Caused by: org. spring framework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 'null'
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSsl(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:103) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.customize(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:61) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeSsl(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:366) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeConnector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:343) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
... 8 common frames omitted                                                                 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:130) ~[spring-core-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:151) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
... 15 common frames omitted
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong in this case. here is my application.yml

```html
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
    exposure:
      include: health,info,prometheus
spring:
  application:
    name: AzureKV
server:
 port: 8443
 ssl:
  enabled: true
  key-alias: certName
  key-store-type: AzureKeyVault
  trust-store-type: AzureKeyVault

azure:
 keyvault:
    enabled: true
    uri: <uri>
    client-id: <client ID>
    client-key: <Secret>
    tenant-id: <tenant-ID>
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: can you share `application.properties ` file

Comment: I don't have application.properties I only have applications.yml that i have shared above @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: @AravindR Can you provide your code once, will check it.

Comment: @DasariKamali based on the link I attached above for the keystone part there is no need for any specific code. It is just the configuration and the POM file. I can attach the POM here is that what you need? Can you take a look at the attached link?

Comment: @AravindR Yes, provide your POM.xml file here.